# Altering Cassandra Compression at production best practices, is nodetool upgradesstables preferred?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, production, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

We have a cassandra keyspace which has 2 tables in production. We have changed it's compression strategy from `LZ4Compressor` (which is default) to `DeflateCompressor`

using 
`ALTER TABLE "Keyspace"."TableName" WITH compression = {'class': 'DeflateCompressor'};`

As we have around 300 GB data in each node of my cassandra 5 node cluster with replication factor 2. Is 
`nodetool upgradesstables` recommended or not as best practice.

From all the sources that we have read

> If necessary

I can use nodetool upgradesstables command. But I want to know **what is actually the best practice** as our data it is in production?

Sources :

> When you add compression to an existing column family, existing SSTables on disk are not
>   compressed immediately. Any new SSTables that are created will be compressed, and any existing SSTables will be
>   compressed during the normal Cassandra compaction process. If necessary, you can force existing SSTables to be
>   rewritten and compressed by using nodetool upgradesstables (Cassandra 1.0.4 or later) or nodetool scrub

After all nodes complete `upgradesstables` A large no of exceptions are being encountered in my cassandra logs

UPDATE - After running `upgradesstables` now my cluster is throwing a lot of errors

Sample 
`

> ERROR [ReadRepairStage:74899] 2018-04-08 14:50:09,779
>   CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[ReadRepairStage:74899,5,main]
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed
>   out - received only 0 responses. at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver$RepairMergeListener.close(DataResolver.java:171)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$2.close(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:182)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseIterator.close(BaseIterator.java:82)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver.compareResponses(DataResolver.java:89)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.AsyncRepairCallback$1.runMayThrow(AsyncRepairCallback.java:50)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_144] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_144] EBUG
>   [ReadRepairStage:74889] 2018-04-08 14:50:07,777 ReadCallback.java:242
>   - Digest mismatch: org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestMismatchException: Mismatch for key
>   DecoratedKey(1013727261649388230, 715cb15cc5624c5a930ddfce290a690b)
>   (d728e9a275616b0e05a0cd1b03bd9ef6 vs d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e)
>   at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.DigestResolver.compareResponses(DigestResolver.java:92)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.ReadCallback$AsyncRepairRunner.run(ReadCallback.java:233)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_144] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_144] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:79)
>   [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_144] DEBUG
>   [GossipStage:1] 2018-04-08 14:50:08,490 FailureDetector.java:457 -
>   Ignoring interval time of 2000213620 for /10.196.22.208 DEBUG
>   [ReadRepairStage:74899] 2018-04-08 14:50:09,778 DataResolver.java:169
>   - Timeout while read-repairing after receiving all 1 data and digest responses ERROR [ReadRepairStage:74899] 2018-04-08 14:50:09,779
>   CassandraDaemon.java:229 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[ReadRepairStage:74899,5,main]
>   org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed
>   out - received only 0 responses. at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver$RepairMergeListener.close(DataResolver.java:171)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$2.close(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:182)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseIterator.close(BaseIterator.java:82)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver.compareResponses(DataResolver.java:89)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `nodetool upgradesstables` it writes new SSTables from existing but using the new options that you specified. This is IO-intensive process that may affect performance of your cluster, so you need to plan it accordingly.  You also need to have enough disk space to perform this operation.  This command should also run as the same user that runs Cassandra.

It's really depends on your needs - if it's not urgent, you can simply wait until the normal compaction occurs, and then data will be re-compressed.

Comment: Can you suggest what should be the rollback strategy if upgradesstable fails on a single node after compression strategy has been changed ? I couldn't find any documentation regarding the same.

Comment: With what error it's failed? If it's failed, then the original table stays, and continue to be used as-is...

Comment: It has not failed as of now, but my question is regarding the rollback strategy. 
Should we run upgradesstables again ? if so, until how many retries ?
Will that table not fail when during normal compaction process recreates the sstable.

Comment: Compression is quite simple operation, and I wonder why it should fail. You can remove compression as rollback strategy, but it's not required. Anyway, we'll need to understand why it's failed, maybe it's not a result of compression

Comment: Hi @Alex, after running upgradesstables, now the number of exceptions in my cluster on each node has increased to around 19000 ( Sample error added to description )

There is no spike in my CPU and RAM usage.

Could you please suggest what could be the possible reason? 

Thanks

Comment: Did you run `upgradesstables` under the same user as cassandra runs? If not, try to check permissions for data files & correct them if necessary

Comment: I did check the permissions, using the command `ls -l` for the data files created in the specific node.
It's the same permission for the node that is misbehaving and the other node that is not  
One specific node that is misbehaving , it has Continuous HIGH CPU than the other nodes and `nodetool tpstats` show High number of dropped mutations for this node.

Comment: Do you see any other warnings or errors in the log? For me it looks like that nodes are overloaded.

Comment: Logs : http://prntscr.com/j3nbpl

Why only a specific node misbehaved and be overloaded of a 5 node cluster ? Each having similar data and same configuration.

On the affected node a specific table has a high Count of Dropped mutation which is around `Dropped Mutations: 530.34 KiB` than any other node which has around `Dropped Mutations: 577 bytes`.

Comment: What Cassandra version do you use

Comment: My casssandra version is 3.10 
Details 
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

Comment: Dropped mutations are usually the first signal of the node overloaded. I see that error happens when it tries to perform repair during read. I would recommend to do following: perform explicit repair using `nodetool repair`, check system.log for entries about GC pauses, etc. - they could cause read timeouts, check logs for errors about big number of thumbstones, etc.

Comment: Hi @Alex, can you help here ? It's the same query, I have moved it to a question with details.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788478/casssandra-single-node-specific-table-high-dropped-mutations